# Safe removal of external hard disk causes keyboard, trackpads and ports to stop working every time

Tags: windows-8, mac

The title sums up the problem. Problem started about couple months ago suddenly without me doing anything differently. I've tried quite a few different brand of external hardisks and it does the same thing. It seems only external hard disks cause this problem since USBs and others work fine

Everyt ime I safely remove the external hard disk:
- the keyboard, trackpad and ports will stop working except for the bluetooth mouse I'm using.
- anything plugged in after the safely removal will not be read by the computer.
- The only way to reset the functions is to restart the laptop.

I tried working around the problem by:
1. installing safe removal software,but the only way i can get to safely remove the hard disk is to disable it.
2. As for my main external hard disk that I frequently use (WD passport 1TB), i can safely remove it using WD software without making my laptop a vegetable.

However about a week ago, the computer starts forbidding me from disabling the hard disk and WD software won't start unless I unistall and reinstall it.

My laptop is a macbook pro running with dual OS; mac os and windows 8 64bit. Pretty much standard factory spec for the laptop.

THANKS! really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: Is this happening on the osx side as well?

Comment: No, it only happens in windows-8.  Thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have an unsigned driver in your system

Do a system restore and then install a signed copy of the same driver

Do not try to remove unsigned drivers. You may permanently damage windows 8

The unsigned driver is most likely to be something you recently installed for eg the naked driver for android

In some cases, the unsigned driver may not even be related to any of the devices

Windows updates will worsen the problem.

Comment: I will try this. Will post updates whether it works for me or not. Thanks!